# Find an equation of this form: $y = ax^2 + bx + c$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for an equation who can pass thought the following points :

$x = 0, y = 0$

$x = 50, y = 60$

$x = 100, y = 0$

I've take a look at this kind of equation, but I didn't find a way to fill my needs.

$y = ax^2 + bx + c$

Do you know any process in order to find this kind of equation ?

Comment: If you put these three points in your equation, you have a system of three linear equations.

Comment: Or rather 2 equations, since you can calculate the value of $c$ with almost no effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the points into the equation and you have to solve 3 linear equation with 3 unknowns. So for $(0,0)$, you have:

$$0 = a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 + c \iff c = 0$$

Now for $(50,60)$ we have:

$$60 = a \cdot 50^2 + b\cdot 50 \iff 250a + 5b = 6$$

And at last for $(100,0)$, we have:

$$0 = a \cdot 100^2 + b \cdot 100 \iff -100a = b$$

Now just substitute into the second equation and the rest should be easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm feeling so stupid ...

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered in a more general way using [Lagrange Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) which has general formula: $$P(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n {P_j(x)}$$
where
$$ P_j(x)=y_j \prod\limits_{k=1}^n {\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}} $$
for $k\neq j$ if we have a collection of points $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$.

So applying this to your problem:
We want the polynomial to go through points $(0,0),(50,60),(100,0)$ now applying the above equations gives:
$$ P(x)= \frac{\left(x-x_2\right) \left(x-x_3\right) y_1}{\left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_1-x_3\right)}+\frac{\left(x-x_1\right) \left(x-x_3\right) y_2}{\left(x_2-x_1\right) \left(x_2-x_3\right)}+\frac{\left(x-x_1\right) \left(x-x_2\right) y_3}{\left(x_3-x_1\right) \left(x_3-x_2\right)}$$
thus after substituting in the values from your question:
this simplifies down to:
$$ P(x)=-\frac{3}{125} (x-100) x=\frac{12 x}{5}-\frac{3 x^2}{125} $$
which if you plug in the value $x=0,x=50,x=100$ give the corresponding $y$ values. But the above process works for a general number of points. So given any number of points the above method will output the minimum polynomial such that it goes through all the given points.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=0,y=0$ in given equation. You will get $c=0$.

Now substitute $x=50,y=60$ and $x=100,y=0$. you will get two equations in two variables which you can solve to get $a,b$.

I'll leave the solving part for you as you'll get some practice doing it.